# C++ class static member initialization

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using Qt 5.2.1 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS.
Here is the definition of my class (.h):

```
class RtNamedInstance
{
    // [... other code here ...]

public:
    static int _nextInstanceNumber;
    static QMutex _syncObj;
};
```

and here my implementation (.cpp):

```
#include "rtnamedinstance.h"

// Initialize static members
int RtNamedInstance::_nextInstanceNumber = 0;
QMutex RtNamedInstance::_syncObj(QMutex::Recursive);

RtNamedInstance::RtNamedInstance(QString instanceName)
{
    QMutexLocker(&_syncObj);    // (*)

    // [... other code here ...]
}
```

The compiler exits with the following error on line marked `(*)`:

> rtnamedinstance.cpp: In constructor
>   'RtNamedInstance::RtNamedInstance(QString)': rtnamedinstance.cpp:9:27:
>   error: '_syncObj' declared as reference but not initialized

What am I missing?

Comment: To start with you need to define a `QMutexLocker` *variable*. Right now you have an expression which creates a *temporary* `QMutexLocker` instance, and once that expression is over (which is immediately) the instance is destructed and you don't actually lock anything outside that no-op expression.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I am really a stupid boy... I wasted minutes on that... but you are right: I've simply forgot to type the QMutexLocker variable name!!! Now it works fine... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @JoachimPileborg, I was simply forgetting to type the QMutexLocker variable name... and this confused somehow the compiler...

The correct code is (.cpp):

```
#include "rtnamedinstance.h"

// Initialize static members
int RtNamedInstance::_nextInstanceNumber = 0;
QMutex RtNamedInstance::_syncObj(QMutex::Recursive);

RtNamedInstance::RtNamedInstance(QString instanceName)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&_syncObj);

    // [... other code here ...]
}
```